# group policy preferences missing in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, group-policy

I have Windows 7 Professional 64-bit which is part of a workgroup network (no Windows server or Active Directory). I have an MMC console containing local group policies for Administrative and Non-Administrative users.

I am trying to find a setting for disabling "hide file extensions for known file types" (among many other things) and Internet searches all claim this is possible using "Group Policy Preferences" which are supposed to be included on my Windows 7 computers; however, I cannot find this "Preferences" option anywhere. I tried both Start -> gpedit.msc and also adding Group Policy Objects as a snap-in to MMC, and they both only show three options: Software Settings, Windows Settings, and Administrative Templates - no Preferences.

All the tutorials I have read (including TechNet) seem to indicate it should just "be there", but I assure you it isn't!

Comment: All of the tutorials you are reading are for Group Policy, not Local Policy.

Comment: Ok, but when I add snap-in to MMC it's clearly labelled "Group Policy Object", so you can understand the mistake

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh848751.aspx

> Unlike Group Policy settings, which apply to both local computer policy and Active Directory policy, Group Policy preferences only apply to Active Directory policy.

Maybe you can't use them without a domain and Active Directory

Comment: Thanks. It was really confusing because I found you could download it for Windows XP. However, I finally came across this article which explains that you in fact need a server (Server 2008 or 2003) and a client (Windows XP, Vista, 7/8). http://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/17026-preparing-your-network-for-group-policy-preferences